# Вызвать закрытие Push menu Jasny-Bootstrap прир выборе пункта меню

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Я использовала Push menu Jasny-Bootstrap http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas. Но хочу чтобы при выборе любого пункта меню оно пряталось. Прячется оно только если кликнуть на тело страницы.

HTML

```
<nav class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation" style>
        <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Клиенты <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav"> 
                                <li><a href="#" id="m_sales">Продажа</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Заказ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Оплата</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Мой jquery:

```
$('#m_sales').click(function(){  
    $('.navmenu').offcanvas('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#m_sales').click(function(){  
    $('nav').offcanvas('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Таким образом должно получиться:

```
$(".navmenu-nav").unbind().on("click", function () {
        $(".navmenu").offcanvas("hide");
});
```